# How to pass data from a custom angular element to the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller and element directive:

```
        ngModule
            .controller('summaryCtrl', [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
                $scope.loaded = false;
                $http
                    .get('some/item/'+itemId) //how do I get this itemId
                    .success(function(data){
                        $scope.data = data;
                        $scope.loaded = true;
                    })
                    .error(function(data){
                        //TODO
                    });
            }])
            .directive('cpSummary', function(){
                return {restrict: 'E', templateUrl: 'some/path.html'};
            });
```

and I want to use the directive something like this:

```
<cp-summary item-id="{id}" ng-controller="summaryCtrl"></cp-summary>
```

the item-id attribute get's set by the parent controller that is rendering the cp-summary elements in a ng-repeat. So I'd just like to know if it's possible to get the `item-id` attribute value inside the `summaryCtrl`.

Comment: If I understand you want just pass `itemId` to summaryController yes? This controller well be used only with this directive?

Comment: Look at this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPJYdX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a controller for your directive. and then you can pass the `item-id` to the directive controller and do the stuff.

```
app.directive('cpSummary', function(){
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: 'some/path.html',
                scope: {
                    item_id: '=itemId'
                },
                controller: ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
                    $http
                         .get('some/item/'+$scope.item_id)
                         .success(function(data){
                             $scope.data = data;
                             $scope.loaded = true;
                         })
                         .error(function(data){
                            //TODO
                         });
                }]
            };
        });
```

Comment: this solution will work if attribute is `item-id="id"`

Comment: Is it possible to pass an array to the `controller:` property? like `['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){/*...*/}]` otherwise when the code gets minified `$scope` and `$http` will become `a, b`.

Answer (score 1):

As you wanted to pass `id` to you directive then you should include that variable inside directive isolated scope. It should be `{{id}}` instead of `{id}` & then use `@` inside your directive. `@` is for one way binding. Also assign the controller from directive.

**Markup**

```
<cp-summary item-id="{{id}}"></cp-summary>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('cpSummary', function(){
    return {
       restrict: 'E', 
       templateUrl: 'some/path.html',
       scope: {
          item_id: '@itemId'
       },
       controller: 'summaryCtrl'
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module("App", []);

app.directive("myDirective", function() {
    var itemFunction = function(scope, element, attributes) {
        scope.item-id= attributes["myDirective"];
  };

  return {
    restrict: "A",
    template: "<p></p>",
    link: itemFunction
  };
});
```